# What's the difference between mapDispatchToProps and {action}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So i've been wondering for a long time what is the **difference between**

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)
```

**and**

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {action})(ComponentName)
```

I've been using the second version but i don't know if that's a good practice.
Any feedback would be useful since i'm really wondering if there is any difference and if there isn't why is everyone using the mapDispatchToProps() instead of just exporting the actions like {action}?
I'm guessing if you have a lot of action's you would use the mapDispatchToProps but if you only have 3-4 why wouldn't you just export them like {action} in connect?

Comment: Well, we can't really tell what's the difference since `mapDispatchToProps` is just a variable that could hold any value.

Comment: Personally, I have been using mapDispatchToProps instead of {action}, my guess is the same as yours for having more than 1 action, you would use mapDispatchToProps , not sure

Answer (score 1):

It's questionable what you mean about `mapDispatchToProps`, since this argument can be an object or a function.

if it's about rewriting your object as a variable like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { action1, action2, action3 }
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)
```

vs:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { action1, action2, action3 })(ComponentName)
```

It wouldn't be much a matter of **good practice**, but about a matter of personal preference and/or your teammates.

On the other hand, `mapDispatchToProps` could also be a function. You could question which is better to pass as argument: function vs object. The benefit about defining as function you can read at the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function):

> Defining mapDispatchToProps as a function gives you the most flexibility in customizing the functions your component receives, and
> how they dispatch actions.

Therefore if you want to customize your prop dispatch function you could define as function like below:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: event => dispatch(myAction1(event.target.value)),
    addItem: () => dispatch(myAction2(ownProps.itemId))
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName)
```

Above a simple example where you have a prop `onClick`, that already handles the expected `event` argument. The function also takes `ownProps`, where you can use at your dispatch function as needed (like the second prop function).

But if you don't see that need to customize your dispatch functions, then you can keep passing only an object as you do already.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad practice. It is actually recommended in the `react-redux` documentation itself.

> Because this is so common, `connect()` supports an “object shorthand” form for the `mapDispatchToProps` argument: if you pass an object full of action creators instead of a function, connect will automatically call `bindActionCreators` for you internally.

> We recommend always using the “object shorthand” form of `mapDispatchToProps`, unless you have a specific reason to customize the dispatching behavior.

You can find all related info in [this page of the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object)

I hope this clears your doubt.